# How to bind Selected Folderpath along with its Foldername to textbox while dealing with FolderBrowserDialog Box?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, folderbrowserdialog

The following is my code...By this, I can get FolderBrowserDialog Box, but Once I select any folder from this dialog box and click 'Ok'. I didn't get the selected FolderPath and its foldername in the textbox which is beside the Browse button. Please correct me...

**View.xaml:**

```
            <Grid>....
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Height="25" IsReadOnly="True" 
                    TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="200"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups,Path=DataContext.FoldernameWithPath}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="4" Content="Browse" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,20,0,20" MinWidth="51"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups,Path=DataContext.OpenFolderCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Height="25" IsReadOnly="True" 
                TextAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="200"
                Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups,Path=DataContext.FoldernameWithPath,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Text porpert is binding mode default oneway. add Mode=TwoWay.

Comment: No...I didn't get yet..@Byoung Sam Moon

Comment: hmm.. check OnPropertyChanged implementaion.

Comment: I have added OnPropertyChanged Implementation of mine...Please check it once @Byoung Sam Moon

Answer (score 0):

Try the following OnPropertyChanged function:

```
        protected void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope...I didn't get still ..@Denis Schaf

Comment: Finally,I got it by adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ...Anyways thank you for helping me.